# Автопрокрутка выпадающего длинного списка combobox javafx

Tags: javafx, прокрутка, combobox

В длинном списке combobox при открытии списка нужно показать определенный элемент. Выделить его не проблема. Не знаю как прокрутить к нему скрол.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comboBox.setOnShown(event -> ((ComboBoxListViewSkin)comboBox.getSkin()).getListView().scrollTo(element));
```

Где `element` - либо индекс нужного элемента, либо сам элемент.

Comment: Спасибо)) точно!